# Extract files from a zip folder with sub folders into a single folder

Tags: python, file

I have a zip folder with several subfolders.
testfolder.zip contains files in the given format

> ```
> testfolder/files 1,2,3
> testfolder/Test1folder/files 5,6
> testfolder/Test2folder/files 7,8
> ```

I need the output as

> testfolder/files 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

I am able to unzip the folder with its subfolders but not in the desired way.

This is my attempt so far

```
import glob
import os
import zipfile
folder = 'E:/Test'
extension = '.zip'
zip_files = glob.glob(folder + extension)
for zip_filename in zip_files:
    dir_name = os.path.splitext(zip_filename)[0]
    os.mkdir(dir_name)
    zip_handler = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, "r")
    zip_handler.extractall(dir_name)
```

Any help will be very appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: subfolders are also zipped? or just folders?

Comment: only the main folder is zipper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
zip_handler.extractall(dir_name)
```

with something like this:

```
for z in zip_handler.infolist():
    zip_handler.extract(z, dir_name)
```

This should by taking each file in the archive at a time and extracting it to the same point in the directory.

UPDATE:
Apparently it still extracts them relatively. Solved it by adding a few lines of code to your original snippet:

```
for p, d, f in os.walk(folder, topdown= False):
for n in f:
    os.rename(os.path.join(p, n), os.path.join(dir_name, n))
for n in d:
    os.rmdir(os.path.join(p, n))
```

This will move the files into the base folder and delete all empty folders that remain. This one I have tried and tested.

Comment: sorry that does not solve the issue. Still getting the older output of unzipped folder with subfolders

Comment: Sorry, it took a bit of time, got held up in something. Check the update. It should do.

Comment: Thanks ! this works although there is a minor problem. The empty subfolders are also getting created.

Comment: The last line should've taken care of that.

Comment: Yes it did. It was an indentation error from my part. Sorry for the minor mistake and thanks again for the help :)